# Haskell instance Ord difficulties

Tags: haskell, types

I have a type that looks like this, and I would like the `compare` function to only take into account the size of the integer.

```
data Cell = FromLeft Coordinate Int
          | FromTop Coordinate Int
          | FromDiagonal Coordinate Int
          | Empty Coordinate
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

The following code works, but I would prefer something more elegant

```
instance Ord Cell where
  compare (FromLeft _ x) (FromLeft _ y) = compare x y
  compare (FromRight _ x) (FromLeft _ y) = compare x y
  [...]
```

Comment: This is not a good `Ord` instance, since different values will compare as equal even if they differ in the `Coordinate` field. Also, how is `Empty` supposed to compare?

Comment: @leftroundabout yes, you've made me realize that ```Ord``` really isn't what I'm after. It feels like in Haskell, you spend a lot of time trying to work around the type system, only to realize that you should have been listening to it instead.

Comment: You might consider defining a new type for your `Ord` instance, rather defining it directly on `Cell` (much like there is no `Monoid` instance for any numeric type, but rather separate instances for `Product` and `Sum` types).

Comment: @chepner: possible, but I daresay it's better to not define any `Ord` instance at all but simply work with helpers like `comparing` if e.g. sorting of some `Cell`s is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an auxiliary function:

```
extractInt :: Cell -> Int
extractInt (FromLeft _ x) = x
extractInt (FromTop _ x) = x
extractInt (FromDiagonal _ x) = x
extractInt Empty = ???
```

and then

```
instance Ord Cell where
  compare c1 c2 = compare (extractInt c1) (extractInt c2)
```

**But be carefull**: The above instance violates the antisymmetry law that states that if `x<=y` and `y<=x` then `x==y`. So it is not really defining an order but rather a preorder.